# Rails: form_for with json: undefined method to_model for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hash, redis

Converted my site to use redis so a JSON array is sent to my views instead of an ActiveRecord array. Made all the necessary conversions like `model.attribute` to `model['attribute']`.

However, can't figure out getting my form_for to work. User can make a prediction on a game. The same `_form.html.erb` is used to create or update the prediction. The error I get, `undefined method 'to_model' for #<Hash:0x007ff28d5f19c8>` occurs on both of these lines:

```
_form.html.erb
<%= form_for [game, (prediction || Prediction.new)], remote: true do |f| %>
...
<%= link_to "Delete", [game, prediction], method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' if prediction.present? %>
```

**Any ideas?** If you need more info, read below:

The link and partial:

```
# index.html.erb
@games.each do |game|
...
<%= prediction_form_link(@predictions, game) %>
<%= render partial: 'predictions/form', locals: { game: game, prediction: prediction_for(@predictions, game) } %>
```

Basically, load partial with form and pass in `game` and `prediction`, but also determine whether `prediction` already exists to be updated instead of created:

```
def prediction_for(predictions, game)   
  predictions["#{game['id']}"].first if predictions["#{game['id']}"].present?
end
def prediction_form_link(predictions, game)
  if prediction = prediction_for(predictions, game)
... # code that displays what this button looks like. Partial is loaded in a modal.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out after spending lots of time in `pry` and old SO posts. Since I'm now passing JSON, I have to modify `form_for` to use `OpenStruct`, and be very specific about what I want it to do. Basically had to modify the partial and my `js.erb`s.

```
# _form.html.erb
form_for(OpenStruct.new(prediction || {}), as: :prediction, remote: true, url: (prediction ? game_prediction_path([game['id']], [prediction['id']]) : game_predictions_path(game['id'], Prediction.new)), method: (prediction ? :put : :post) ) do |f| %>
...
<%= link_to "Delete", game_prediction_path([game['id']], [prediction['id']]), method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' if prediction.present? %>
```

New `OpenStruct` to either grab the existing `prediction` or `{}` for a new one. I'm not even sure about which of these are absolutely necessary, but it's working. Classify as a `:prediction` and then specify the paths, parameters, and methods in the two situations (`#create` or `#update`), since I'm using the same partial for both.

Then I had to slightly modify my `create.js.erb`, `destroy.js.erb`, and `update.js.erb` files to send the data back to the views `as_json`.

```
# create.js.erb for example
$('#game-<%= @game.id %>').modal("hide");
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('#user-prediction-<%= @game.id %>').html('<%= j prediction_form_link(@predictions.as_json, @game.as_json) %>');
$('#user-prediction-<%= @game.id %>').append('<%= j render partial: "predictions/form", locals: { game: @game.as_json, prediction: prediction_for(@predictions.as_json, @game.as_json) } %>')
```